# Spark Job error GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I am running a spark job and I am setting the following configurations in the spark-defaults.sh. I have the following changes in the name node. I have 1 data node. And I am working on data of 2GB.

```
spark.master                     spark://master:7077
spark.executor.memory            5g
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://namenode:8021/directory
spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory              5g
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
```

But I am getting an error saying GC limit exceeded.

Here is the code I am working on.

```
import os
import sys
import unicodedata
from operator import add 

try:
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    from pyspark import SparkContext
except ImportError as e:
    print ("Error importing Spark Modules", e)
    sys.exit(1)


# delimeter function
def findDelimiter(text):
    sD = text[1] 
    eD = text[2] 
    return (eD, sD) 

def tokenize(text):
    sD = findDelimiter(text)[1]
    eD = findDelimiter(text)[0]
    arrText = text.split(sD)
    text = ""
    seg = arrText[0].split(eD)
    arrText=""
    senderID = seg[6].strip()
    yield (senderID, 1)


conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

textfile = sc.textFile("hdfs://my_IP:9000/data/*/*.txt")

rdd = textfile.flatMap(tokenize)
rdd = rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://my_IP:9000/data/total_result503")
```

I even tried groupByKey instead of also. But I am getting the same error. But when I tried removing the reduceByKey or groupByKey I am getting outputs. Can some one help me with this error.

Should I also increase the size of GC in hadoop. And as I said earlier I have set driver.memory to 5gb, I did it in the name node. Should I do that in data node as well?

Comment: What is the size of data and the number of nodes in the cluster?

Comment: Number if nodes is 1 and size is around 2GB.

Comment: I believe you have more than 10 GB of RAM on your node as you are assigning 5 gb to driver and 5gb to executor.Can you try setting spark.driver.memory to something 2GB

Comment: What different would it make?

Comment: And if I do that should I do that in datanode as well.. Because all the above configurations I did was in namenode alone....

Comment: Also as per your new edit here namenode you mean spark master and datanode as executor right?

Comment: If you have say only 6 GB RAM then 5 gb will be allocated to Driver while executor will have only 1GB left which will cause this exception

Comment: @SachinJanani   Okay got it... and yeah master is the name node and executor is the datanode... But I even tried datanode with 1gb already. Did not work. That is the reasin I increase it to 5g.

Comment: You should have more memory to executor as compared to driver as processing will be done by your executor.So executor should have say 4gb while driver can have say 2gb

Comment: @SachinJanani  by the way I am not facing the error when I don' t run the reduceByKey or groupByKey...

Comment: Tried 1g to driver and 5g to executor.. did not work...

Comment: Yes this is because groupBykey and reduceByKey will involve shufftling

Comment: I think you have very less memory free on your machine not even 2GB thats why its failing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115305/discussion-between-sachin-janani-and-baradwaj-aryasomayajula).

Answer (score 2):

Try to add below setting for your spark-defaults.sh:

**spark.driver.extraJavaOptions** *-XX:+UseG1GC*

**spark.executor.extraJavaOptions** *-XX:+UseG1GC*

Tuning jvm garbage collection might be tricky, but "G1GC" seems works pretty good. Worth trying!!

Comment: Tried this but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

The code you have should have worked with your configuration . As suggested earlier try using G1GC . 
Also try reducing **storage memory fraction** . By default its 60% . Try reducing it to 40% or less. 
You can set it by adding `spark.storage.memoryFraction 0.4`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. I was running my hadoop in the root user of the master node. But I configured the hadoop in a different user in the datanodes. Now I configured them in the root user of the data node and increased the executor and driver memory it worked fine.